# How to authorize a new computer to Play but not to Purchase in iTunes

Tags: itunes, authorization

My need is to authorize one more computer in my family to play my content bought on iTunes. I understood this is possible up to 5 computers. The way to do this seems to be to authorize the computer by login to the iTunes store. But doing this, I am scared the 2nd computer will also be able to purchase  with my iTunes account, which I obviously don't want!

Does anyone know how to control this?

Answer (score 3):

You can authorise a computer to play/access iTunes-purchased content without logging in to the store.

In the iTunes menubar: Store > Authorize This Computer…

You will be asked to enter your Apple ID and password. These are the same credentials you use for the iTunes Store. The iTunes Store will still ask for an Apple ID and password when anyone tries to make a purchase.